# Yii2 - supersized-widget slide show issue

Tags: php, slideshow, yii2, banner

I have a problem that needs to be solved. I need to include a full screen slide show in a `Yii2` Basic app.

In `Yii1.xx` I used to use with no problem Supersized slide show extension, but in `yii2` I can't install Yii2 Supersized widget via composer.json (I update composer) but it says it can not find the widget. So i download the zip file and place it under `vendor vendor/yiisoft/yii2-supersized-widget-master.`

The deal is that I don't know how to activate it, I think due to the lack of namespace in the instructions (that are inexistent) it always throws me the error -> `Class 'Supersized'` not found.

The link to the supersized page is:

https://github.com/xjflyttp/yii2-supersized-widget

Is there someone that knows how to put this widget working in the `site/index.php` page of `Yii2`.

Or is there a better and ready working full screen slideshow to use with `Yii2`?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install it with composer using dev-master.

```
"xj/yii2-supersized-widget": "dev-master"
```

Worked for me.

Comment: SOLVED. Many thanks to Jorgen. It installed well. I used namespace xj\supersized;